# Is mixing Java and Kotlin a bad idea?

Tags: java, kotlin, jvm

I've been trying to learn Kotlin but I find it to be a lot easier to learn when I can slowly apply it to things I'm working on in Java. Is it a bad idea to mix Java and Kotlin in production?

I know the overall goal is to use one or the other but is there anything wrong with the latter?

Comment: Interoperation with Java is made for that purpose, you can add new code or migrate old one to Kotlin at your own pace.

Comment: So there's not issue with doing so? It's not looked down upon?

Comment: There is nothing wrong and no one should look down upon it. What you should ask yourself is: do you need to mix them? Why do you want to mix them? Is for the purpose of just learning on how to? If so, go ahead. If not, you need to have a good reason of doing so.

Comment: Alright, thanks!
One more thing, is there a reason why the question got downvoted? (I'm new to stack overflow and I thought it was a valid question.)

Comment: The question looks a little too opinion-based to fit here; SO is mostly for how-to questions. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com might be a better fit for architecture/design questions like this one.

Comment: Definitely doesn't *hurt* to know both and how to make them interoperate! Even though Kotlin's the recommended language for Android, there are a lot of existing projects that were developed in Java, and if they want to migrate it'll be a bit-by-bit process like you're doing now. It's a real-world scenario, y'know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objectively, we can say that compatibility with Java was one of Kotlin's main objectives, according to [the official docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/faq.html#is-kotlin-compatible-with-the-java-programming-language):

> Kotlin is 100% interoperable with the Java programming language and major emphasis has been placed on making sure that your existing codebase can interact properly with Kotlin. You can easily call Kotlin code from Java and Java code from Kotlin. This makes adoption much easier and lower-risk. There’s also an automated Java-to-Kotlin converter built into the IDE that simplifies migration of existing code.

Many features are designed specifically to ease [calling Java from Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html) or [vice versa](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-interop.html): for example, the fact that property accessors are implemented in the same way as normal Java accessor methods, and the ability to implement SAM interfaces; and where Kotlin implements things differently, there are often annotations or other ways to use a Java-style implementation.

And in my own experience, there are no issues with mixing Java and Kotlin classes. Many of our projects have both (new classes written in Kotlin, a few old ones converted but many still in Java), and I'm not aware of any significant problems. I also converted a major project from Java to Kotlin, one class at a time — and after each one, everything still compiled and tested and ran perfectly.

Of course, new projects can be written in Kotlin from the start; but if you already know Java, mixing in some Kotlin is absolutely an option, and may be the easiest approach. You can convert parts to Kotlin piecemeal, when convenient, or leave them in Java long-term; pretty much everything just works, and you benefit from the parts that *are* in Kotlin. (You might even find that the way you write Java code benefits from knowing Kotlin!)

Comment: I have an extremely similar experience with Kotlin and Java. We used to only do Java, until some random guy from the company convinced us to switch to Kotlin. After a while we converted almost everything (I'd say about 85% maybe?) that was in Java to Kotlin, but we still have projects where both are used. Everything that was new, we did in Kotlin.